# Abort all dispatch_semaphore_wait

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

In iOS, GCD provides semaphores to synchronise access to a limited supply of resources.

In my program, I'm reading data from an external device. That external device can be disconnected, and the program will never signal the semaphore again. So we end up in the following situation:

- Thread 1 is waiting on the semaphore

  ```
  if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.writeSem, /* 15s timeout */)) {
  ```
- Thread 2 knows that no wait will be successful

Eventually, the `dispatch_semaphore_wait` times out, returns `NO` and Thread 1 resumes running.

How can I immediately fail this `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, so Thread 1 would instantly get the `NO` and continue his life? Is there some kind of "cancel semaphore" that I could use?

Comment: You could obviously just (a) set some state variable indicating that it was cancelled and then (b) post a signal on that semaphore.

Comment: That has the potential to create race conditions with the reading/writing of that state variable. This is pretty much the raison d'être of condition variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without extra "machinery" a semaphore is the wrong abstraction for this. There is no "cancel semaphore wait" operation other than to signal it, and when signaled, without more information, you don't know whether it signaled because of success or termination. So you could add an external flag that indicates whether the signal was for completion or early termination, but then you have to properly guard that flag against concurrent reads and writes.

The canonical primitive to use here is a condition variable, and the standard Cocoa example would use an NSCondition. A trivial example might look like this:

```
NSCondition* cond = [NSCondition new];
__block BOOL workSucceeded = NO;
__block BOOL subordinateFinished = NO;
NSTimeInterval timeout = 5.0;

// Waiter
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [cond lock];
    while (!subordinateFinished)
    {
        if (![cond waitUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: timeout]])
        {
            // Timed out...
            NSLog(@"Timed out waiting for work at: %@", [NSDate date]);
            break; // don't keep waiting
        }
        else if (workSucceeded)
        {
            // Signaled to indicate that work was done
            NSLog(@"Work finished at: %@", [NSDate date]);
        }
        else //if (!workSucceeded)
        {
            // Signaled to indicate premature termination.
            NSLog(@"Work prematurely terminated at: %@", [NSDate date]);
        }
    }
    [cond unlock];
});

// Actor
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Work started at: %@", [NSDate date]);
    BOOL completed = NO;

    // Uncomment one of these to trigger each case
    // Finish on time:
    //sleep(1);
    //completed = YES;

    // Fail Early:
    //sleep(1);

    // Time out
    //sleep(timeout + 1);

    // ... and when done
    [cond lock];
    workSucceeded = completed;
    subordinateFinished = YES;
    [cond signal];
    [cond unlock];
});
```

The important things to understand here is that `workSucceeded` and `subordinateFinished` are protected by the condition's lock, and are never read or written by anyone who doesn't hold the lock. What's often not clear to folks on their first experience with NSCondition is that the acts of calling `-wait`, `-waitUntilDate:` or `-signal` all cause the calling thread to *temporarily* give up the lock, with the understanding that when execution resumes on that thread, that it will once again be holding the lock.

Hope this helps.